# set background image in div full screen width

Tags: html, css

I have an image background set in in wrapperlp at top of page. It works fine but its width is set at 1000px. I need this image to span across the full width of the screen, but when i change width nothing happens.

css

```
#wrapperlp {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #wrapperlp {
        width: 90%;
        min-width: 100px;
    }
}

#headerlp {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#para {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}


#game_img {
    height: 250px;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top:-35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#video_play {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top:-30%;
    width:280px;
    padding-right:10px;
}


#spacer {            
    height: 40px;           
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding-top:20px;
}

.reward_img {
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

html

```
 <div id="wrapperlp">
        <div style="background-image: url(); height: 430px; width: 1000px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-width: 100%;">
            <div id="headerlp">text</div>
            <div id="para">text</div>
            <div id="game_img"><</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video_play">text</div>
    <div>
        <div id="spacer">
            <div style="position: relative; float: left">text</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I understand your question, but your HTML is a little messed up and your question statement is a little confusing. If you put it clearly would be better :)

Answer (score 2):

Besides other answers here, you can also use values `cover` or `contain` in `background-size`:

**cover**
The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

```
background-size: cover;
```

**contain**
The contain value specifies that regardless of the size of the containing box, the background image should be scaled so that each side is as large as possible while not exceeding the length of the corresponding side of the container.

```
background-size: contain;
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Answer (score 1):

If you consider putting img inside of the div. This should do it.

```
  <div style="width:200px; height:200px">
     <IMG SRC="URL.PNG" width="100%" height="100%"/>
   </div>
```

To do this as a background image of the div, use

```
   height: 200px;
   width:200px;
   background-image: URL(image.PNG)
   background-size: contain;
```

In your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
```

Hope its help you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `get the content(image) to the full width of screen`,you must `set width` in percentage;that is `100% of screen`

```
width:100%;
```

always give `max-width` in `px` and `width` in `percentag`e when `using max width`